# Google Change of Address of a Subdomain to a Domain

Tags: web, subdomain, google-search-console

I've got a bit of a problem with Google's Change of Address function on the Google Webmaster tools. I hope that I got the right part of the Stack Exchange for this.

Basically, for six years I've been using a blogging platform blogsome.com (which hosts domains like http://site-address.blogsome.com), which is basically a hosted wordpress server. I've had no complaints about it, until they recently announced that they would close down on a very, very short notice.

With this, I found it a good opportunity to set up a domain of my own (let's call it http://site-adress.net for now). Setting up the domain and website went well, but when I went to Google Webmaster Tools to tell it about the change of address, this proved to be surprisingly difficult. In particular, when I tried the "Change of Address"-option on the dashboard, I get the message that this option is not available for subdomains.

What method would there be to correctly tell google that my site has changed? I cannot use 301-redirects, because 1) I do not have access to do that on blogsome, and 2) blogsome will be shutting down really soon (read: within a week; the news was on a very short notice, and I spent most of that time actually setting up the website). I've also read somewhere that you should keep your old site alive for 180 days, and again that is no option for me either.

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to use a .htaccess file (plain text file)

And put this inside it and upload it to your site.

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.yournewdomain.com/
```

If you cant do that you might be able to upload a new index.php with the following inside it.

```
<?php
header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: http://www.yournewdomain.com/" );
exit(0)
?>
```

If you cant do that either, then say what you can actually do on the server?
Do you have any actually access to files? Or can you edit the templates?

You should be able to move it in gwt i'm not 100% sure, I never done it with a subdomain or a blog-hosted site. So I might be wrong here.

Add your new domain with the blog to your gwt account and get it verified.
Then in GWT goto your bloghosted site then to Site Configuration > Change of address
And then select your new domain under the "Tell us the URL of your new domain" part and hit Submit

Comment: GWT Change of Address tool doesn't allow you to move subdomains.

Comment: Considering this didn't answer any of the original points it isn't much good. Trying to find an answer to this same question and this is just "noise"